# React functional component - How to access children method from Parent

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component (Sidebar) that I would like to access a method inside the children (Checkout).

The Sidebar is more of a "Wrapper" HTML, which can have different children. In this case its form fields (Checkout), which has its own state.

Sidebar contains a submit button that upon clicking, I want to get inside "Checkout" and do logic such as validating the "Checkout" local state etc.

```
function Sidebar({ children }) {
  function submit() {
    //I want to access validate method in child...
  }

  return (
    <div className="Sidebar">
      {children}
      <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checkout = () => {
  let [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const handleInputChange = useCallback((event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    switch (name) {
      case "email":
        setEmail(value);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }, []);
  const validate = () => {
    // I want to call this method and access local state, when
    // "submit" is clicked from the parent
  };

  return (
    <Sidebar>
      <h3>Checkout</h3>
      <input name="email" value={email} onChange={handleInputChange} />
    </Sidebar>
  );
};
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Below is Codesandbox version:

[image: Edit unruffled-maxwell-hvxfc]

Comment: If you know that you always have one child and the method is always called validate, you can use useRef (and then `child.current.validate()`). If you can't make this assumption you'll need to pass to children a method allowing them to subscribe to the event, so each interested child passes a callback into something like `props.subscribe` and the parent keeps a list of methods to call on submit

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova - I added useRef, then wrapped the contents in a div and added the ref attribute to the child. When I do console.log(children.ref.current); - I get the html node, but I can't see the .validate(). How can I expose the validate? 
See -> https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-maxwell-hvxfc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In this example `Sidebar` us a child of `Checkout`, not a parent, so you're passing a method from a parent to child, you should follow Luis Silva answer.

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: The question is worded backwards and confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough, you'll want to pass the method in the sidebar:

```
 <Sidebar validate={validate}>
```

And then just invoke the method:

```
function submit() {
    validate();
    //I want to access validate method in child ...
  }
```

Comment: This answer does not address that the question is backwards.  The OP question asks how to access child from parent.. but they are actually just accessing the Parent from a child, which is simply passing a function as a prop TO the child